# Jquery Hiding Select from dropdown options

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, select, hide

I am sorting dropdown list options with jquery sort. How can I hide select as item in dropdown?

[Here is my fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/tC4Z2/)

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="12">c</option>
    <option value="4">b</option>
    <option value="5">e</option>
    <option value="6">d</option>
    <option value="8">f</option>
</select>

 $('#mySelect').html($('#mySelect option').sort(function (x, y) {
                                            return $(x).text() < $(y).text() ? -1 : 1;
                                        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

**[see updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tC4Z2/1/)**

```
$(function() {
  //make a plugin for sort item you can use in fucture also for sort item 
    $.fn.sortList = function() {
    var list = $(this);
    var items = $("li", list).get();
    items.sort(function(a, b) {
        var listItem1 = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var listItem2 = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (listItem1 < listItem2) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $.each(items, function(i, itm) {
        list.append(itm);
    });
   }
  //plugin code end

  // Now call the plugin
     $('#mySelect').sortList();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Find and delete the option node:

```
$("#mySelect > option[value='']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using CSS (only) Selectors

```
#mySelect option[value='']
{
    display: none;
}
```

`Issue:` You will see 'Select' on first time

Try if you ok with that. else;

Use jquery using CSS selectors

```
$("option[value='']").remove();
```

or better (if you have few selects in the page):

```
$("#mySelect option[value='']").remove();
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/tC4Z2/10/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the "Select" option hidden. Do you mean you want it hidden from the sorting?

Another way to put it: Sort everything in the drop-down except the first option, Select. If so, consider:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mySelect = $('#mySelect'),
            mySelectOptions = $('option', mySelect),
            selectOption = mySelectOptions.first();
        mySelect.html(mySelectOptions
                .filter(function (index) {
                    return index !== 0;
                })
                .sort(function (x, y) {
                    return $(x).text() < $(y).text() ? -1 : 1;
                })
            ).prepend(selectOption);
    });
```

Using the .filter() method, you can extract all the options in the drop-down, except the first one (or you could filter based on other criteria...). Caching the first option away, we can safely sort all the other options and prepend the first option "Select" back in as the first child element.